# Understanding reinterpret_cast error with some templated method

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, memory-alignment, reinterpret-cast

I'm trying to compile the following code with some c++ ARM compiler.

```cpp
void pairs_converter(const mem_t& mem, uint16_t* data) {/* some stuff */}

template <typename StringT>
inline 
void to_string(const mem_t& mem, StringT& s)
{
    s.resize(24);
    pairs_converter(mem, reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&s[0]));
}
```

and I get the following error code :

```bash
error: cast from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char>, char>::value_type*' {aka 'char*'} to 'uint16_t*' {aka 'short unsigned int*'} increases required alignment of target type [-Werror=cast-align]
         pairs_converter(mem, reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&s[0]));
```

from what I understood it looks like an alignment problem between some words and octets but I'm not fluent enough with c++ to understand how to tackle this compiler error.

I would be gratefull for some more detailed explanations on this c++ error !

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(&s[0])` is going to lead to undefined behavior if you use the resulting pointer at all.

Comment: the template alone would not trigger this error. If `s` is a pointer to `uint16_t` all is fine. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` should not be necessary.  If the code doesn't compile without the `reinterpret_cast` I suspect it was already broken from the get-go.

Comment: A `char*` can  point to *any* byte, which can be stored without a specific alignment requirement. Most other types cannot. In particular if you have a 16-bit value, it might require an even address. Then the odds are about 50/50 that this code would work. Not great!

Comment: Do you have some reason to expect `&s[0]` to be aligned to at least `alignof(uint16_t)`? If not, the resulting pointer will be unusable as already mentioned.

Comment: @Useless It will be aligned to at least `__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`, which is `>= alignof(max_align_t)` and `>= alignof(uint16_t)`

Comment: If you know what `StringT` is, maybe. But it's a template parameter, so who knows how its internal storage is aligned, or what `operator[]` does?